# Where did ftps credentials tab go for Azure's function app deployment center?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

FTPS Credentials tab used to be available next to the settings and logs tabs in the deployment center for my Azure function app, now it's not showing up... Anyone else experiencing this?

I was expecting to see the ftps credentials on the deployment center page for my Azure function app.

Comment: Share the screenshot. It will be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure about Function app? please share If you have any screenshots. As Web apps service still has FTP credentials tab in Deployment center [image](https://i.imgur.com/opTl6wy.png)

Answer (score 5):

I have this hacky solution that's working today but might be fixed later.

After creating the resource via the Azure portal the FTPS Credentials tab in Deployment Center is hidden in the Azure Portal.

If you go to Configuration > General Settings, you'll see that the "Basic Auth Publishing Credentials" is on "on". This is correct, but if you select "off" (don't save!) then go back to "on". And then click Save, it saves. Go back to Deployment Center and there should be your FTPS credentials tab.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: 7 years later and this still did the trick for me... sigh

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing the same. The Credentials tabs is accessible inside App Services but not in Function Apps.

What I can recommend to you is, simply download publish profile to access FTPS credentials if you need.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft intentionally removed the FTPS Credentials button: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1342921/have-azure-removed-ftp-credentials-tab-from-azure